# How to check if If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used for touchpad?

Tags: linux-kernel, gentoo, touchpad, input

I'm seeing the following warning in `dmesg`:

```
[    2.631179] psmouse serio2: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN1218 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
...
[    2.819449] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input10
```

The touchpad works, but I feel that it is not working as well as it used to. I'm on Gentoo with a custom configured kernel. I've recently switched to other distros and came back to Gentoo and reconfigured the kernel from the ground up. I don't believe I did something out of the ordinary with regards to the input devices, so this *might* be a bug as suggested in `dmesg`.

```
$ uname -r
5.1.4-gentoo

$ grep -E 'INPUT|I2C_HID|HID_RMI' .config
CONFIG_RFKILL_INPUT=y
CONFIG_INPUT=y
CONFIG_INPUT_LEDS=m
CONFIG_INPUT_FF_MEMLESS=y
CONFIG_INPUT_POLLDEV=y
CONFIG_INPUT_SPARSEKMAP=m
# CONFIG_INPUT_MATRIXKMAP is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_JOYDEV is not set
CONFIG_INPUT_EVDEV=y
# CONFIG_INPUT_EVBUG is not set
CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSE=y
CONFIG_INPUT_JOYSTICK=y
CONFIG_INPUT_TABLET=y
CONFIG_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MISC=y
# CONFIG_INPUT_AD714X is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_BMA150 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_E3X0_BUTTON is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MSM_VIBRATOR is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_PCSPKR is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_MMA8450 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_APANEL is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_ATLAS_BTNS is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_ATI_REMOTE2 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_KEYSPAN_REMOTE is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_KXTJ9 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_POWERMATE is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_YEALINK is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_CM109 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_UINPUT is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_PCF8574 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_ADXL34X is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_IMS_PCU is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_CMA3000 is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_IDEAPAD_SLIDEBAR is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_DRV2665_HAPTICS is not set
# CONFIG_INPUT_DRV2667_HAPTICS is not set
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS_INPUT_EVDEV=y
CONFIG_USB_PWC_INPUT_EVDEV=y
CONFIG_SND_JACK_INPUT_DEV=y
# CONFIG_SND_HDA_INPUT_BEEP is not set
CONFIG_HID_RMI=y
CONFIG_I2C_HID=y
```

> If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used

**My question**: how do I check if those are not used?

> you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep "psmouse.synaptics_intertouch"
```

Returns nothing, so nothing to set there.

Answer (score 0):

If you've compiled `i2c-hid` and `hid-rmi` as modules, you can check if they've gotten automatically loaded or if things break when you unload them.

> $ sudo sysctl -a | grep "psmouse.synaptics_intertouch
>
> Returns nothing, so nothing to set there.

That's a kernel commandline parameter. Alternatively, if you compiled psmouse as a module, you can unload it and modprobe it again while passing `synaptics_intertouch=1` as a parameter.

Comment: A priori you should also be able to set the parameter by something like `echo 1 > /sys/module/psmouse/parameters/synaptics_intertouch`.