# Synaptics touchpad, i2c-hid and hid-rmi

Tags: configuration, touchpad, synaptic, hid

I have a similar question as asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/521012/how-to-check-if-if-i2c-hid-and-hid-rmi-are-not-used-for-touchpad): how should I interpret this line from syslog:

```
psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN1ef3 SYN1e00 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
```

I can confirm that neither i2c-hid nor hid-rmi are used (loaded; both are loadable modules). But what is the preferable configuration here - have either (which?) or both of them loaded OR set the intertouch parameter?